# Generating explode: false for array query parameters in swagger.json using openapi 3.0.1 and .Net Core 3.1 and Swashbucle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, query-string

I am developing some Openapi 3.0.1 APIs with .Net Core 3.1 using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger and SwaggerGen v6.1.4. I want to build an API that receives an array query parameter; in ASP.NET Core the default call for an API like this is something like

`https://someUrl/?values=valore1&values=valore2`

but due to caller needs I want to accept something simpler, like

`https://someUrl/?values=valore1,valore2`

In other words, I want to generate a swagger.json that has an explode: false node

```
  parameters:
    - name: values
      in: query
      explode: false
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
```

while the default is explode: true.

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I managed to use a custom `QueryStringValueProvider`:

```
public class QueryStringCommaSeparatedValueProvider : QueryStringValueProvider
{
    public QueryStringCommaSeparatedValueProvider(
      BindingSource bindingSource,
      IQueryCollection values,
      CultureInfo culture) : base(bindingSource, values, culture)
    { }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        var result = base.GetValue(key);

        if (result == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var values = result.SelectMany(r => r.Split(","));

        return new ValueProviderResult(
          new StringValues(values.ToArray()),
          Culture);
    }
}
```

The relative factory:

```
public class QueryStringCommaSeparatedValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var query = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
        if (query != null && query.Count > 0)
        {
            var valueProvider = new QueryStringCommaSeparatedValueProvider(
              BindingSource.Query,
              query,
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            context.ValueProviders.Add(valueProvider);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

... has to be inserted in Mvc options in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ValueProviderFactories.Insert(0,
              new QueryStringCommaSeparatedValueProviderFactory());
        });
```

Comment: This was a great help for me. However, this would cause any parameter (e.g., a string parameter) with a comma to be split. I've found this article that expands on this concept further to allow this to be set for an individual parameter: https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.Samples.AspNetCore.QueryStringBinding